# Click not registering on Image element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get a click to register on my image tag to get the coordinates of the image click to position an svg element on top of it. As far as I understand, the way I have my code should account for bubbling events, but I'm not 100% certain. Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong, information I might be missing from it? As of now, nothing runs.

```
$(".playing-field").on("click", "#picture", function(e) {
  var offset = $("#picture").offset();
  var relativeX = (e.pageX - offset.left);
  var relativeY = (e.pageY - offset.top);
  console.log(relativeX, relativeY);
});
```

I forgot to add HTML before...

```
<div class="playing-field">
    <img id="picture" src="assets/images/image.jpg">
    <svg class="speechbubbles" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
</div>
```

I tried the code in Jsfiddle without my CSS, and it works, but when I do add the CSS, it doesn't. I'm not that familiar with CSS rules, so can someone tell me why it would interfere with the clicking of the image?

```
.playing-field {
position: relative;
height: 500px;
width: 100%;
}

#picture{
position: absolute;
}
.speechbubbles{
position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Can you make a [stack snippet](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270944/feedback-requested-stack-snippets-2-0) with the HTML?

Comment: Is `#picture` a unique ID? And please share some HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You code runs very well.

Try This https://jsfiddle.net/2bm4zjdz/1

```
$(".playing-field").on("click", "#picture", function(e) {
  var offset = $("#picture").offset();
  var relativeX = (e.pageX - offset.left);
  var relativeY = (e.pageY - offset.top);
    alert( 'x : ' + relativeX + ' y :' + relativeY);

});
```

Comment: Hm. It works in Jsfiddle, but not in chrome. I'm going to have to find a way to get around that I guess. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looking around it seems that offset doesn't work in chrome so you will need to use position like so

```
$(function () {
    $('#picture').click(function (e) {
        var offset = $(this).position();
        var relativeX = (e.pageX - offset.left);
        var relativeY = (e.pageY - offset.top);
        alert('x :' + relativeX + ' y :' + relativeY);;
    });
});
```

Comment: I just figured it out that I could have the click register on the container and make an if statement that would not register the click if it is outside the parameters of the image. It works fine now, thanks for your help! :)